# Optimize draw calls for merged mesh with individual scaling

Tags: three.js

I have 10K cubes and the draw calls is very high, well.. 10K

You can see this here:
http://thegrook.com/three.js/merge1.html

If I combine all cubes to a single mesh, the draw calls is down to one.

You can see this here:
http://thegrook.com/three.js/merge2.html

But in the first example, I change the scaling of each cube based on the distance from the camera,

So no matter what is the zoom - the cube staying the same size on screen, and this give me the effect that I need:

The closer the camera is - the lower the density between the cubes

In the second example - this doesn't work, because the scaling affect the whole mesh and not per cube

Any idea how to achieve the density effect with less draw calls?

Thanks.

*** Edited 1 ***

I managed to solve this with instancing and render 250K objects and stay on 60fps

When I zooming out - the objects are overlapping - that's ok for my case.

But what's wrong is all the textures are flickering a lot..

Seem like there are no fixed drawing order for all the instancing

There is a way to fix this?

Here is an example:
http://thegrook.com/three.js/instancing3.html

* just zoom out with the mouse wheel

*** Edited 2 ***

Looks like If I disabling  the depthWrite on the material - the problem is solved

Is this the right solution?

Comment: I would use instancing for that. Learning about it and implementing it will take considerable effort, however. By the way, what is the use case for which the effect you want is beneficial?

Comment: Not sure why implementing it requires significant effort... it shouldn't. Check out this npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/three-instanced-mesh

Comment: Thank you for guidance, It's for a map with buildings with real geolocation coordinates, the size of the buildings need to be constant, no matter what is the zoom, so the user can see the details...

Comment: The instance call will draw everything according to the instancing buffer and how things are ordered in it. If you want to sort things, you'd sort it somehow and then update the instance buffer to reflect that. The flickering is due to z-fighting. When they scale past a certain point the triangles start overlapping and everything goes crazy. You might want to limit this and prevent it from happening altogether. Otherwise, you might have to offset them slightly but not sure how this would work.